# Is the Objective-C Runtime API Available outside Darwin?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, portability, darwin

Objective-C has [an amazing API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html) for reading and changing its own runtime environment, but I can only find documentation for this API from Apple. Is the API only available on machines running a Darwin OS or is it actually part of Objective-C in general?

If its specific to Darwin is it at least available in the [GNUstep framework](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnustep/)?

#### Edit - What I'm Looking for Specifically

Specifically I am writing an XSD based serializer/deserializer and I would like to be able to create/modify class definitions based on XSD documents that are parsed during runtime, in order to make the framework more intuitive.

Comment: What particular functions of the Cocoa runtime do you wish to use that you are unable to find in the GNUstep runtime? With such information people might be able to answer yes/no/alternative *x* is available/etc. (Edit your question.)

Comment: @CRD Well I'm not sure what is available and what is not available from the GNUstep runtime. The only reference I could find to their particular runtime API features was this [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Objective_002dC.html#Objective_002dC) to the GCC Objective-C runtime features. Are you aware of more extensive documentation on GNUstep specific features?

Comment: Maybe start at [Objective-C Compiler and Runtime FAQ](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ)? A few clicks from there gets you to at least to header files with obvious similarity to Cocoa.

Comment: @CRD Hmmm that's an interesting document. So it seems that the functions are only available if I install GNUstep **and** link against "Étoilé's ObjectiveC2 framework". By the way, I added an edit to answer your original question.

Answer (score 1):

All the versions of Objective-C that I've seen have some facilities for mucking about with introspection and/or dynamic generation of classes at runtime.

The details will be different per different runtime and they may not all have feature parity (example;  the apple runtime has blocks and that hasn't been ported everywhere).

Comment: For Objective-C with GCC I could only find [this list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Objective_002dC.html#Objective_002dC) of supported runtime management features, and it **does not** include dynamic generation of classes. TBH that's the feature I'm really looking for, too. Do they actually allow dynamic generation of classes and just not document it?

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom that's the compiler capabilities.  Look at the runtime api. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modern-GNU-Objective-C-runtime-API.html#Modern-GNU-Objective-C-runtime-API

Answer (score 1):

Your updated question indicates you specifically wish to add/modify class definitions.

Following the reference [Objective-C Compiler and Runtime FAQ](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ) mentioned above in the comments we find about `libobjc2` which is part of GUNStep, and it’s [runtime.h](https://github.com/gnustep/libobjc2/blob/master/objc/runtime.h) contains the method:

```
Class objc_allocateClassPair(Class superclass, const char *name, size_t extraBytes);
```

for creating classes - this appears to be the same as the one in Cocoa.

You might find Mike Ash's [Creating Classes at Runtime in Objective-C](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html) helpful.

HTH